# how to get key after using map function in R

Tags: r, dictionary, functional-programming

I'm trying to use map function in R and I have something like this

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
map(x, function (e) e + 100)
```

Is there a way to get the keys a, b inside the map function?

For example if I wanted to print

```
a 1
b 2
```

Comment: You can use `imap`.  Not clear about the ouptut format  Do you need `imap(x,  ~ setNames(.x, .y))`  If you want the output with added 100 `imap(x,  ~ setNames(.x + 100, .y)`)

Comment: `imap` is the preferred ... but an alternative is `map2(x, names(x), ...)`. One advantage of this mindset is that it applies on base-R `Map` and `mapply` as well: `Map(function(obj, nm) {...}, x, names(x))` (though ultimately I wish that R had a trivial native analog for `imap`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @akrun

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2))
l <- x %>% imap(~{list(.x,.y)}) 
do.call(rbind,l)

  [,1] [,2]
a 1    "a" 
b 2    "b"
```

or even simpler:

```
do.call(rbind,x)
  [,1]
a    1
b    2
```

seems to answer exactly your expected output